# MYSQL: why does the ORDER BY time differ for the 2 almost identical queries

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, sql-order-by

```
SELECT *
FROM `resumes` AS r
LEFT JOIN seeker_data_cached AS c ON r.user_id = c.user_id
ORDER BY r.user_id

SELECT *
FROM `resumes` AS r
LEFT JOIN seeker_data_cached AS c ON r.user_id = c.user_id
ORDER BY c.user_id
```

r.user_id and c.user_id are indexed. Why do these queries have very different execution times and is there anything that can be done to speed up the second query?

Comment: If there is no difference in the output (which appears to be the case), why not just use the first one?

Comment: What does comparing the execution plan of the two queries tell you?

Comment: @Benjam So that we can learn.

Comment: @Wiseguy- I agree, but if the OP was looking for a usable solution, the question had to be asked.

Comment: different number of rows in the tables could impact time

Comment: @Eugene: Can you post the schema of both tables and associated row counts? It's hard to do an apples to apples comparison like this because chances are the tables differ which will probably impact the query times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MySQL documentation contains [a section on `ORDER BY` optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html) that has, right near the top, a bulleted list of things to check when performance isn't what you expect.  So, first thing might be to go through that list.

Many of them, we can rule out based on the information you've given, but many of them involve things we don't know from your question but that you would probably know.

If that doesn't help, run both queries through `EXPLAIN` and that may tell you why performance for one is different than the other.

I'd be inclined to see what happens if you change `ON r.user_id = c.user_id` in your second query to `ON c.user_id = r.user_id` based on the bit in the documentation linked above where it talks about the situation where "[t]he key used to fetch the rows is not the same as the one used in the ORDER BY".